# replace inner brackets with atom

Tags: list, clojure, brackets

How does one convert

```
((((3 5 6) 3 4) 4) 3 5 3)
```

to

```
(n n n 3 5 6 n 3 4 n 4 n 3 5 3)
```

? I ask this because I suspect the solution would speed up flattening algorithms.

Edit: I guess the *real* question being asked here is whether or not a parenthesis can be treated as an atom in clojure, or more broadly, lisp.

Comment: If I'm reading your question right, what you want could only be accomplished by parsing the above as text. By the time the reader is done with it, there _are_ no parentheses - it's already been converted to nested lists.

Comment: Hi Alex, could those nested lists then be converted to text?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example

```
(loop [[x & xs :as xxs] '((((3 5 6) 3 4) 4) 3 5 3)
       acc []]
  (if (seq xxs)
    (if (sequential? x)
      (recur
       (concat ['n] x ['n] xs)
       acc)
      (recur xs
             (conj acc x)))
    acc))
```